# pytorch difference in 1.1.0 and 1.3.0 in Parameter

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to learn PyTorch and have tried running some code that I got from the Kaggle website.

```
# Get all hidden layers' weights
for i in range(len(hidden_units)):
  fc_layers.extend([
    TrainNet.model.hidden_layers[i].weight.T.tolist(), # weights
    TrainNet.model.hidden_layers[i].bias.tolist() # bias
  ])
```

This gives the following error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-65f871b6f0b7> in <module>
  4 for i in range(len(hidden_units)):
  5     fc_layers.extend([
----> 6         TrainNet.model.hidden_layers[i].weight.T.tolist(), # weights
  7         TrainNet.model.hidden_layers[i].bias.tolist() # bias
  8     ])

AttributeError: 'Parameter' object has no attribute 'T'
```

If I print out the type of 'TrainNet.model.hidden_layers[i].weight' it is indeed type Parameter.
This block of code works without error on the Kaggle website run in there notebook (Google colab I believe) where the version of Torch is 1.3.0.

On my home machine where the error occurs my Anaconda distribution which I have just updated is running Torch 1.1.0.

Is this the source of the error and how do I sort it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class `Parameter` is a subclass of [Tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/nn.html#torch.nn.Parameter) hence has all the attributes of a `torch.Tensor` [class](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/tensors.html#torch-tensor)

`Tensor.T` was introduced in [1.2.0](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.2.0/tensors.html?highlight=tensor#torch.Tensor.T) and hence is not available in your 1.1.0

You can either update the pytorch version or use the permute method in it's place as below example

```py
>>> t = torch.Tensor(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(2,3,4))) # -> random Tensor with t.shape = (2,3,4)
>>> t.shape
torch.Size([2, 3, 4])
>>> list(range(len(t.shape)))[::-1]
[2,1,0] # This is the sequence of dimensions t.T will return in 1.2.0 onwards
>>> t = t.permute(list(range(len(t.shape)))[::-1])
>>> t.shape
torch.Size([4, 3, 2])
```

It is equivalent to doing transpose of a matrix, i.e., reversing the sequence of dimensions but in N dimensional tensors

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I wonder why Anaconda is not using 1.2.0 as standard